# Sharepoint online arrange Grids in 4 columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, image, quick-links

Simple task,i am using the quicklink webpart to create a dashboard on my homepage,i need to arrange the grids in 4 columns in a 3 column page layout. The maximum column i get when editing the webpart is 3. Note i tried other webpart like image gallery but could't get the same design.

Can anyone advise if there is a webpart out there that allow this customisation? Last option will be to create a spfx webpart which will involve coding.

[image]

Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did: change the page layout to two column section And a vertical column section and i get 4 grid as required. I can play with the size by changing the css if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge for now there is no built-in web part will reach your requirements. You may need to create a spfx web part for more detailed settings.